# Typescript convert string in json to string literal

Tags: typescript, types, string-literals

I have a json config file checked into my project that looks something like this:

```
{
  "flag": "one"
}
```

and I want to check the type of this json file, with a type that includes string literals.

```
import someconfig from './configs/someconfig.json'
type Config = {
  flag: 'one' | 'two'
}


const config: Config = someconfig
```

which results in this error:

```
error TS2322: Type '{ "flag": string; }' is not assignable to type 'Config'.
  Types of property 'flag' are incompatible.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"one" | "two"'.

 const config: Conf = someconfig
        ~~~~~~
```

This means I cannot check the types of any json files against a type that uses literals. This is explained as widening types in this [typescript issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27913). Still, I want to know if I can convert strings to string literals somehow. I have found an example https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/literal-types.html which sort-of widens types from strings to string literals. Is it possible to accomplish this from a json file?

my tsconfig.json file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./lib/",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "lib": ["es2015", "es2016", "es2017"],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "es2017",
    "allowJs": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "examples/**/*.ts",
    "custom.d.ts",
    "testing/**/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: String literals are a concept for type-safety used in static analysis and not during runtime. Furthermore you are directly loading a JSON file that cannot be assigned safely this way. Have you possibly considered to export the data in the JSON file as a module instead? Using TypeScript you'd even be able to leverage the type system and have code completion and type checking while writing the configuration file. That is something Webpack is using for example as well.

Comment: I could export the configs as modules, I liked the idea of forcing a config file to be purely data. The purpose of the configs being checked into the project in the first place was as [examples](https://github.com/andykais/scrape-pages/tree/master/examples) for developers using the library. I was afraid that typescript syntax would be confusing to a js user who was not exposed to it. It may be the right move though.

Comment: An alternative, if you want to stick to pure JSON, is to use a schema or parser that checks for validity which is usually not necessary in the first place. You could just `JSON.parse(...) as IConfig` and then manually check the semantics of the parsed values with some helper methods. With your code you're trying to achieve type-safety powered by TypeScript during compilation which isn't feasible.

Comment: @andykais There is a TypeScript feature request involving [const assertions](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-4/#const-assertions) which addresses your use case: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32063 - Without its implementation, it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue and solved it by creating a custom check using an string enum.

My approach consists of these elements:

- A custom Typescript Error Class that gives an error in the browser itself. You can define the type of the error and the error messages yourself.

  ```
   class CustomError extends Error {
      constructor(type: string, message:string) {
        super(message);
        this.name = type;
    }
  }
  ```
- A helper function to check if a value is part of the enum, if not, throw an error with some information using the Error Class.

  ```
   const checkValueInEnum = (value:any, Enum:any) => {
       let match = false;
       for (const prop in Enum) {
           if (Enum[prop] === value) {
               match = true;
               break;
           }
       }
       if (match) {
          return true 
       } else {
           throw new CustomError("Enum error", ` Flag '${ value }' does not exist in '${ JSON.stringify(Enum)}'`);
       }
    }
  ```
- Then use the helper function with an if statement to get either a true or the error.

  ```
   enum flagConfig {
       One = 'one',
       Two = 'two'
   }

   const someConfigJson = {
       flag: 'two'
   }

   if (checkValueInEnum(someConfigJson.flag, flagConfig)) { // Returns True or throws an error.
       // Code
   }
  ```